# Best way to implement Transaction Logic single Database with Multiple DB Context Class in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, transactions, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Any once suggest me how to implement Entity Transaction Logic for same Database with Multiple Context Class.

I have Implemented DB Context following...

WMS DB Context(Which keeping the Parcel Handling process).

```
public WMSContext()
        : base("Name=shopOrderContext")
    //: base("Name=WMSContext")
    {
        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
        var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 15 * 60; // value in seconds
    }
```

Second one is Order Processing DB(Its have Customers Order).

```
 public shopOrderContext()
        : base("Name=shopOrderContext")
    {
        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
        var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 15 * 60; // value in seconds
    }
```

To maintain the Transaction I have been implemented the following manner...

```
 public ActionResult WarehouseConfirmVesselDate(string ConfrimVesselDate, string manifestNumber, string manifestStatus, string Remarks = null)
    {
        string Result = "Failed";
        //
        ManifestMaster manifestMasterList = new ManifestMaster();
        try
        {
            string UserName = Convert.ToString(Session["userName"]);
            TempData["TempManifestNumber"] = manifestNumber;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfrimVesselDate))
            {
                using (objWmsContext = new WMSContext())
                {
                    using (var transScope = objWmsContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            #region Update Confirm Vessel Date form Warehouse User
                            GLSLabelRepository GlsRepbo = new GLSLabelRepository();
                            manifestMasterList = objWmsContext.ManifestMasterRecordes.Where(p => p.ManifestNumber == manifestNumber).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (manifestMasterList.Status == GlsRepbo.ShipmentOpen)
                            {
                                if (manifestMasterList.VesselDate == null || manifestMasterList.VesselDate == Convert.ToDateTime(ConfrimVesselDate))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (manifestMasterList.Country.ToUpper() == inCode.ToUpper())
                                        {
                                            // Update Vessel Date 
                                            Result = objWhRepository.UpdateConfirmVesselDate(ConfrimVesselDate, UserName, manifestNumber, manifestStatus, Remarks, objWmsContext);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            //Comments by Prakash on Sprint 15 dated on 05-11-2014.
                                            //In Sprint 15 ,Warehouse Shipment processed based on the Manifest Number.Because of that the Process changed into the Following manner.
                                            //Step 1 : On Giving Vessel Date(Warehouse Module).New Process need to update the Only Vessel Date 
                                            //Step 2 : On Close Shipment .To block the Franchisee to add more parcel in that shipment list(based on the Country,Ready to Shipment Date and Vessel(Air/Ocean).
                                            //Step 3 : On Complete Shipment.Update the ShipmentStatus=True,OrderStatus= "Sent From VA" and Send Email to Customer.

                                            //Update Only Vessel Date.If this is the Case i need to work on the Vessel Report
                                            Result = objWhRepository.UpdateConfirmVesselDateManifest(ConfrimVesselDate, UserName, manifestMasterList.ManifestNumber, manifestStatus, Remarks, objWmsContext);
                                        }
                                        ManifestMaster MMbo = objWmsContext.ManifestMasterRecordes.Where(p => p.ManifestNumber == manifestNumber).FirstOrDefault();
                                        MMbo.VesselDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ConfrimVesselDate);

                                        MMbo.ModificationHistory = manifestMasterList.ModificationHistory + "  --  WAREHOUSE CONFIRMATION VESSELDATE --  USER :  " + UserName + "  Vessel Date :  " + Convert.ToDateTime(ConfrimVesselDate);
                                        if (MMbo.Country.ToUpper() == inCode)
                                        {
                                            //For India shipment Warehouse does not required to process Completed shipment.Because BOMBIO Shipment Label print form their sevice.
                                            MMbo.Status = GlsRepbo.ShipmentCompleted;
                                            MMbo.ShipmentUnits = 1;
                                            MMbo.Remarks = "For India there is no shipment label printing process.That why as soon as updating Vessel Date WMS made to complete the Shipment and Default Pallet Label is One. " + "<br/>---------- " + Convert.ToString(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name) + " and WMS System Comments ADDED on Complete Shipment at  " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ---------------- <br/><br/>" + MMbo.Remarks;
                                        }
                                        objWmsContext.SaveChanges();
                                        transScope.Commit();
                                        transScope.Dispose();
                                        Session["MNumber"] = MMbo.ManifestNumber;
                                        if (Result != "Failed" && !Result.Contains("Transaction aborted"))
                                        {
                                            //manifestMasterList.VesselDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ConfrimVesselDate);
                                            //manifestMasterList.ModificationHistory = manifestMasterList.ModificationHistory + " --WAREHOUSE CONFIRMATION VESSELDATE-- USER : " + UserName + " Vessel Date : " + Convert.ToDateTime(ConfrimVesselDate);
                                            //objWmsContext.SaveChanges();

                                            if (MMbo.Country.ToUpper() == dkCode || MMbo.Country.ToUpper().Trim() == seCode)
                                            {
                                                var syncResult = GlsRepbo.CompareVesselListAndSynchedRecordCount(MMbo.Country, MMbo.ReadyToShipDate, MMbo.ManifestNumber);
                                                if (syncResult == "Failed")
                                                    Result = "NotSynched";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        Result = "ERROR while Updating" + ex.ToString();
                                        throw;
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Result = " Manifest List should have same VesselDate :: " + manifestMasterList.VesselDate;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Result = " Manifest List was closed it seems.";
                            }
                            #endregion
                        }
                        catch (TransactionAbortedException trex)
                        {
                            transScope.Rollback();
                            transScope.Dispose();
                            objRepository.writeToLogFile(" Exception :" + trex.Message + "Source :" + trex.Source);
                            objRepository.writeToLogFile(" UpdateConfirmVesselDateManifest  Transaction Aborted Exception message : " + trex.Message);
                            if (trex.InnerException != null)
                            {
                                objRepository.writeToLogFile("UpdateConfirmVesselDateManifest  Transaction Aborted InnerException message : " + trex.InnerException.Message);
                            }
                            Result = "Transaction aborted. Same data is accessed by another user. Reload the data and Try after some time";
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            transScope.Rollback();
                            transScope.Dispose();
                            objRepository.writeToLogFile(" Exception :" + ex.Message + "Source :" + ex.Source);
                            objRepository.writeToLogFile(" UpdateConfirmVesselDateManifest  Transaction Aborted Common Exception block message : " + ex.Message);
                            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                            {
                                objRepository.writeToLogFile("UpdateConfirmVesselDateManifest  Transaction Aborted Common InnerException block message : " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            }
                            Result = "Common block Exception Transaction aborted. Same data is accessed by another user. Reload the data and Try after some time";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Result = "Server Received Selected WarehouseNos and ConfirmVessel Date is Empty,Retry Once Again...";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            loggfile.writeToLogFile("Confirm Vessel List got failed for this Manifest#(" + manifestNumber + ") : Message :- " + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                loggfile.writeToLogFile("InnerException" + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }

        }
        return this.Json(Result);
    }
```

You can able to see my comments b/w in the code.I have handling the Update or Insert DB query multiple method call and I passing each method Current DB Context to handle the Transaction.

My clear question here :
1) Am I handling the Transaction Logic right way?

2) It I handling the Transaction Logic like this Which Transaction Id(WMSContext Transaction Id or ShopOrderContext Transaction Id) My code will be consider to Commit or else please suggest me how to maintain the transaction logic for the SAME Database with multiple DB Context Class..

3)I have separate Service Method Class for  ShopOrderContext and WMSContext. Some Scenario I have to Interact with both,here my Question Is it required to Over load the Method to pass the Current Transaction Context Object to each method.

I have been used like this...

```
//Update Only Vessel Date.If this is the Case i need to work on the Vessel Report
Result = objWhRepository.UpdateConfirmVesselDateManifest(ConfrimVesselDate, UserName, manifestMasterList.ManifestNumber, manifestStatus, Remarks, objWmsContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Entity Framework provides a good abstraction to the DB (by being an ORM) having multiple EF Context objects that might even map the same table, will NOT provide you an out of the box solution for transaction integrity.

The only 3 ways that I think you would be able to do it are:

- Place all the tables you need in only one EF context.
- OR keep the way you have and now welcome to the nightmare of trying to keep parallel "Work" (threads), where each one is processing each one a transaction, and then you will need to implement a mechanism of "signals" between then in order to provide success/error (rollback) mechanism....
- If you know exactly what you need to do, just create a stored procedure in SQL and place all your complex logic in there and call it on C#.

Personally, to keep the spirit of EF, I would go for the option #1.